# angular.isArray function is not working in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

This is my index page

```
<li class="active" ng-repeat="items in menuItems">
    <span ng-if="angular.isArray(items)">
        <a href="" class="act">{{items}}</a>
    </span> 
</li>
```

This is my controller

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.assests = 'include/assests.html' ;
  $scope.menu = 'include/menu.html' ;
  $scope.footer = 'include/footer.html' ;
  $scope.menuItems = [ 'a' , ['xyz'] , ['abc'] ];
});
```

MenuItems is mix of array and values , but angular.isArray(items) neither evaluate true nor false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411291/angularjs-inline-check-if-an-array-check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<span ng-if="angular.isArray(items)">` will looks for something in your scope named: `$scope.angular.isArray()` ; that obviously does not exists.

I would suggest you to do the following:

```
<span ng-if="isArray(items)">
```

And in your controller, define this function:

```
$scope.isArray = function(obj) {
    return angular.isArray(obj);
}
```

Comment: You gave me perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

just put `ng-if="isArray(items)"` and then in your controller

```
$scope.isArray = function(value){ return Array.isArray(value) }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is other solution, but i won't recomend it to use (it's better to have wrap over angular.functions and do not have direct access from view to angular, but sometime, it could be usefull).

You can set `$scope.angular` property with `angular` value like this:

```
(function(angular) {
 'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.angular = angular;
  }]);  
})(angular);
```

In this case access from view like `angular.isArray` will be transformed to `$scope.angular.isArray`.